# argparse: Associate arguments with another argument

Tags: python, argparse

With argparse, it's possible to repeat an argument and collect all the values into a list:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '-o', 'output2'])
print(vars(args))
# {'output': ['output1', 'output2']}
```

I'm looking for a way to associate flags with each of these arguments, so that it's possible to do this:

```
args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '--format', 'text',
                          '-o', 'output2', '--format', 'csv'])
```

And get an output like this (or something similar):

```
{'output': {'output1': {'format': 'text'},
            'output2': {'format': 'csv'}
           }
}
```

Ideally, these flags should follow the usual semantics - for example, `--format` could be optional, or there could be multiple arguments associated with each `-o` output, in which case they should be passable in any order (i.e. `-o output1 -a -b -c` should be equivalent to `-o output1 -c -a -b`).

Can this be done with argparse?

Comment: Argparse tries to handle flagged arguments in an order-independent manner.  The `output` will be in one list, the `format` in another, without links, defaults or allowances for skipped values.

Comment: I can imagine writing a custom `Action` class (or two) that crates and maintains  a dictionary like that.  For each `-o` it would add an `output` key with default `format`,  A `--format` would look up the latest `output` key, and set its `format`.  The `append` action implements a simple interaction between actions with a common flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the code in [hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48509689/1222951), I've tweaked the implementation to make it more versatile. It consists of 2 custom Action classes, `ParentAction` and `ChildAction`.

## **Usage**

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# first, create a parent action:
parent = parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action=ParentAction)
# child actions require a `parent` argument:
parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', action=ChildAction, parent=parent)
# child actions can be customized like all other Actions. For example,
# we can set a default value or customize its behavior - the `sub_action`
# parameter takes the place of the usual `action` parameter:
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action=ChildAction, parent=parent,
                    sub_action='append', default=[])

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '-l1', '-l2',
                          '-o', 'output2', '--format', 'csv',
                          '-o', 'output3', '-f1', '-f2'])
print(args)
# output (formatted):
# Namespace(
#     output=OrderedDict([('output1', Namespace(list=['1', '2'])),
#                         ('output2', Namespace(format='csv', list=[])),
#                         ('output3', Namespace(format='2', list=[]))
#                         ])
# )
```

## **Caveats**

- Child actions must always follow after parent actions.
  For example, `--format csv -o output1` would not work and show an error message.
- It's not possible to register multiple ChildActions with the same name, even with different parents.

  Example:

  ```
  parent1 = parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action=ParentAction)
  parser.add_argument('-f', action=ChildAction, parent=parent1)
  parent2 = parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', action=ParentAction)
  parser.add_argument('-f', action=ChildAction, parent=parent2)

  # throws exception:
  # argparse.ArgumentError: argument -f: conflicting option string: -f
  ```

---

## **Code**

```
import argparse

from collections import OrderedDict


class ParentAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, default=OrderedDict(), **kwargs)

        self.children = []

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        nspace = type(namespace)()
        for child in self.children:
            if child.default is not None:
                setattr(nspace, child.name, child.default)
        items[values] = nspace

class ChildAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, *args, parent, sub_action='store', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.dest, self.name = parent.dest, self.dest
        self.action = sub_action
        self._action = None
        self.parent = parent

        parent.children.append(self)

    def get_action(self, parser):
        if self._action is None:
            action_cls = parser._registry_get('action', self.action, self.action)
            self._action = action_cls(self.option_strings, self.name)
        return self._action

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        try:
            last_item = next(reversed(items.values()))
        except StopIteration:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self, "can't be used before {}".format(self.parent.option_strings[0]))
        action = self.get_action(parser)
        action(parser, last_item, values, option_string)
```

Comment: I get a syntactical error here in def __init__(self, *args, parent, ...).  I also thought you can not place "parent" after *args?  Is there a fix or something I miss?  I also search for a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 4):

3 parsers operating on a general set of `-o` and `-f` flags:

Simple append - no connection between the 2 `dest`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action='append')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '-o', 'output2'])
print(args)
args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '--format', 'text',
                          '-o', 'output2', '--format', 'csv'])
print(args)

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1',
                          '-o', 'output2', '--format', 'csv',
                          '-o', 'output3', '-f1', '-f2'])
print(args)
print()
```

`nargs='+'`; keeps arguments together, but does not use `format` flags:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action='append', nargs='+')
#parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '-o', 'output2'])
print(args)
args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', 'text',
                          '-o', 'output2', 'csv'])
print(args)

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1',
                          '-o', 'output2', 'csv',
                          '-o', 'output3', '1', '2'])
print(args)
print()
```

Custom classes derived from the `append` class.  Creates a dictionary for each `output`.  `format` modifies the last `output` dictionary:

```
class Foo1(argparse._AppendAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = argparse._copy.copy(argparse._ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, []))
        dd = {'output': values, 'format': []}
        items.append(dd)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)

class Foo2(argparse._AppendAction):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = argparse._copy.copy(argparse._ensure_value(namespace, self.dest, []))
        last = items[-1]   # error if -f before -o
        last['format'].append(values)
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', action=Foo1)
parser.add_argument('-f', '--format', action=Foo2, dest='output')

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '-o', 'output2'])
print(args)
args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', '--format', 'text',
                          '-o', 'output2', '--format', 'csv'])
print(args)

args = parser.parse_args(['-o', 'output1',
                          '-o', 'output2', '--format', 'csv',
                          '-o', 'output3', '-f1', '-f2'])
print(args)
print()
```

produces:

```
1238:~/mypy$ python stack48504770.py 
Namespace(format=None, output=['output1', 'output2'])
Namespace(format=['text', 'csv'], output=['output1', 'output2'])
Namespace(format=['csv', '1', '2'], output=['output1', 'output2', 'output3'])

Namespace(output=[['output1'], ['output2']])
Namespace(output=[['output1', 'text'], ['output2', 'csv']])
Namespace(output=[['output1'], ['output2', 'csv'], ['output3', '1', '2']])

Namespace(output=[{'output': 'output1', 'format': []}, 
                  {'output': 'output2', 'format': []}])
Namespace(output=[{'output': 'output1', 'format': ['text']}, 
                  {'output': 'output2', 'format': ['csv']}])
Namespace(output=[{'output': 'output1', 'format': []}, 
                  {'output': 'output2', 'format': ['csv']}, 
                  {'output': 'output3', 'format': ['1', '2']}])
()
```

Comment: Nice idea. I see a few problems with this approach though - 1) You've hard-coded "format" into `Foo2`, so I'd have to create a copy of `Foo2` for each flag that I want to associate with `output`. 2) `Foo2` is an `_AppendAction`, so if I want a different behavior, I have to rewrite `Foo2` - it'd be better if `Foo2` had an `action` parameter. I'll try to find a way to improve these aspects of your code.

Comment: I inherited from `append` because it was easiest to imitate its call.  I don't think there's anything special in the inherited `__init__`.  The key is that the `format` class has a way of finding and modifying the latest `output` attribute.

Comment: FYI, I've posted my own answer with a tweaked version of your code. Just a heads up in case you were working on improving your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just define `-o` to take two arguments.

```
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', nargs=2, action='append')
```

Then `-o output1 text -o output2 csv`

will produce something like

```
args = p.parse_args(['-o', 'output1', 'text', '-o', 'output2', 'csv'])
assert args.output == [['output1', 'text'], ['output2', 'csv']]
```

You can post-process `args.output` to get the desired `dict`, or define a custom `Action` whose `__call__` method will build the `dict` value itself.

Comment: The problem with this is that the `--format` flag is now essentially mandatory. I can't give it a default value, and if I have, say, 5 different flags associated with each output, the user will be forced to provide all 5 values - in the correct order. This is an acceptable solution if you have one or two flags, but unmaintanable with more.

Comment: @Rawing, this answer fits your question as written.  If you have more general requirements (e.g. `format` being optional or multiple), that needs to be spelled out in the question (preferably a new one).

Comment: @hpaulj I disagree. I asked for a way to associate flags with other arguments, and a required positional argument is arguably not a flag. I suppose I should try to make the question a bit clearer though.

Comment: I agree I don't answer the question as stated, but I don't believe there *is* a positive answer; `argparse` simply doesn't work that way. The closest thing to such an association is how you can add options to a subcommand, but that isn't really applicable here (since you can only specify a single subcommand, not a chain of them, to a single call).

Comment: @Rawing, but if your example had included a `-o` without a following `--format` or with multiple `--format`, it would have been clearer that `nargs=2` wouldn't work.  I could suggest `nargs='+'`, but if you must use flagged options in a particular order, it would be better if you wrote your own parser.