# argparse with multiple subparsers and positionals

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a script, `select_libs.py`, which enables you to choose which libraries to include in some build process. When running this script I want to be able to specify the library name, branch and version. Here are some use cases.

- `select_libs.py`

  - Use script defaults when positionals are not defined.
- `select_libs.py opencv stable 3.4.1`
- `select_libs.py opencv stable 3.4.1 boost development 1.67.0`

So I imagine something as simple as this:

```
import argparse

branches = ["legacy", "stable", "development"]

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='lib configuration')

opencv_parser = subparsers.add_parser("opencv")
opencv_parser.add_argument("opencv_build", choices=branches)
opencv_parser.add_argument("opencv_version", type=str)

boost_parser = subparsers.add_parser("boost")
boost_parser.add_argument("boost_build", choices=branches)
boost_parser.add_argument("boost_version",type=str)

cmd_options = parser.parse_args()
```

The first two use cases both work, but the third:

```
select_libs.py opencv stable 3.4.1 boost development 1.67.0
```

produces this error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: boost development 1.67.0
```

In my head, this should work since each parser have exactly two positional arguments, so it should know that `boost` is not an argument to `opencv` and trigger the `boost` parser accordingly. Clearly I'm wrong, but what have I missed and how can I make it work as intended (if possible)?

My current Python version is `3.5.2`.

Comment: Related (dup?): [argparse: Associate arguments with another argument](//stackoverflow.com/q/48504770)

Comment: @Aran-Fey I don't see how that is related let alone a dup?

Comment: You can't do it with subparsers. That's why it's related, because it offers an alternative solution.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argparse is not suited for this kind of thing. `add_subparsers` assumes that exactly 1 of the sub-commands will be used, so it throws an error if you try to set both `opencv` and `boost`. And other than that, argparse has no concept of arguments being associated with other arguments.

### Option 1

If you don't mind using keyword options instead of positional options, you can use the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48511483/1222951):

```
argv = '-l opencv -b stable -v 3.4.1 -l boost -b development -v 1.67.0'.split()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parent = parser.add_argument('-l', '--lib', choices=['opencv', 'boost'], action=ParentAction)

parser.add_argument('-b', '--build', action=ChildAction, parent=parent)
parser.add_argument('-v', '--version', action=ChildAction, parent=parent)

args = parser.parse_args(argv)
print(args)
# output:
# Namespace(lib=OrderedDict([('opencv', Namespace(build='stable',
#                                                 version='3.4.1')),
#                            ('boost', Namespace(build='development',
#                                                version='1.67.0'))]))
```

### Option 2

Use the [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) argument to make it a mix of positional and named arguments:

```
argv = '-l opencv stable 3.4.1 -l boost development 1.67.0'.split()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parent = parser.add_argument('-l', '--lib', nargs=3, action='append')

args = parser.parse_args(argv)
print(args)
# output:
# Namespace(lib=[['opencv', 'stable', '3.4.1'],
#                ['boost', 'development', '1.67.0']])
```

### Option 3

Parse the arguments manually:

```
argv = 'opencv stable 3.4.1 boost development 1.67.0'.split()

args = {}
argv_itr = iter(argv)
for lib in argv_itr:
    args[lib] = {'build': next(argv_itr),
                 'version': next(argv_itr)}

print(args)
# output:
# {'opencv': {'build': 'stable',
#             'version': '3.4.1'},
#  'boost': {'build': 'development',
#            'version': '1.67.0'}}
```